# Declaring javascript namespaces in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following javascript in a file:

```
var MyNamespace = function () {
    return {
         blockUI: function (options) {
             alert(1);          
         }
    };
}();
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dm0bzzxt/

I want to call:

```
MyNamespace.blockUI();
```

from a typescript file.

I understood how to do it for ordinary javascript functions:

```
declare function blockUI();
```

But can't understand how to do it for the above.

Comment: that isn't valid javascript.

Comment: The OP said he's using typescript.

Comment: @Andy the first block im referring to.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Well spotted.

Comment: Hmm. Seems i have misunderstood things here. Give me a sec.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Isn't it working fine.. other than improving on the syntax like so, (function(){})().. nothing else causing problems. Go ahead and invoke in that manner. Doesn't it work?

Comment: @LakmalCaldera since the namespace is in an own javascript file, typescript is not compiling and saying "Could not find symbol MyNamespace".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare module MyNamespace {
    function blockUI(): void;
}
```

Comment: Aha, module. Thanks Ryan!